# cuda under ubuntu 20.04 don't run since February 22

Tags: 20.04, cuda

In February an new kernel update has run. Since this time cuda 10.1 and the nvidia driver 510 not run.

(base) oem@PC83:~$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

best regards

---

```
(base) oem@PC83:~/Downloads$ dpkg -l |grep headers
ii  libblkid-dev:amd64                                          2.34-0.1ubuntu9.3                                                               amd64        block device ID library - headers and static libraries
ii  libdbus-1-dev:amd64                                         1.12.16-2ubuntu2.2                                                              amd64        simple interprocess messaging system (development headers)
ii  libhwloc-dev:amd64                                          2.1.0+dfsg-4                                                                    amd64        Hierarchical view of the machine - static libs and headers
ii  libice-dev:amd64                                            2:1.0.10-0ubuntu1                                                               amd64        X11 Inter-Client Exchange library (development headers)
ii  libmount-dev:amd64                                          2.34-0.1ubuntu9.3                                                               amd64        device mounting library - headers and static libraries
ii  libnl-3-dev:amd64                                           3.4.0-1                                                                         amd64        development library and headers for libnl-3
ii  libnl-route-3-dev:amd64                                     3.4.0-1                                                                         amd64        development library and headers for libnl-route-3
ii  libselinux1-dev:amd64                                       3.0-1build2                                                                     amd64        SELinux development headers
ii  libsm-dev:amd64                                             2:1.2.3-1                                                                       amd64        X11 Session Management library (development headers)
ii  libx11-dev:amd64                                            2:1.6.9-2ubuntu1.2                                                              amd64        X11 client-side library (development headers)
ii  libxau-dev:amd64                                            1:1.0.9-0ubuntu1                                                                amd64        X11 authorisation library (development headers)
ii  libxcomposite-dev:amd64                                     1:0.4.5-1                                                                       amd64        X11 Composite extension library (development headers)
ii  libxdamage-dev:amd64                                        1:1.1.5-2                                                                       amd64        X11 damaged region extension library (development headers)
ii  libxdmcp-dev:amd64                                          1:1.1.3-0ubuntu1                                                                amd64        X11 authorisation library (development headers)
ii  libxext-dev:amd64                                           2:1.3.4-0ubuntu1                                                                amd64        X11 miscellaneous extensions library (development headers)
ii  libxfixes-dev:amd64                                         1:5.0.3-2                                                                       amd64        X11 miscellaneous 'fixes' extension library (development headers)
ii  libxi-dev:amd64                                             2:1.7.10-0ubuntu1                                                               amd64        X11 Input extension library (development headers)
ii  libxinerama-dev:amd64                                       2:1.1.4-2                                                                       amd64        X11 Xinerama extension library (development headers)
ii  libxmu-dev:amd64                                            2:1.1.3-0ubuntu1                                                                amd64        X11 miscellaneous utility library (development headers)
ii  libxmu-headers                                              2:1.1.3-0ubuntu1                                                                all          X11 miscellaneous utility library headers
ii  libxrandr-dev:amd64                                         2:1.5.2-0ubuntu1                                                                amd64        X11 RandR extension library (development headers)
ii  libxt-dev:amd64                                             1:1.1.5-1                                                                       amd64        X11 toolkit intrinsics library (development headers)
ii  libxtst-dev:amd64                                           2:1.2.3-1                                                                       amd64        X11 Record extension library (development headers)
ii  linux-generic-hwe-20.04                                     5.13.0.44.49~20.04.28                                                           amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-5.13.0-41-generic                             5.13.0-41.46~20.04.1                                                            amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.13.0-44-generic                             5.13.0-44.49~20.04.1                                                            amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-113                                     5.4.0-113.127                                                                   all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.4.0
ii  linux-headers-5.4.0-113-generic                             5.4.0-113.127                                                                   amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-5.8.0-63-generic                              5.8.0-63.71~20.04.1                                                             amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                                       5.4.0.113.117                                                                   amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04                             5.13.0.44.49~20.04.28                                                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-41                            5.13.0-41.46~20.04.1                                                            all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.13.0
ii  linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-44                            5.13.0-44.49~20.04.1                                                            all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.13.0
ii  linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-63                              5.8.0-63.71~20.04.1                                                             all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.8.0
ii  uuid-dev:amd64                                              2.34-0.1ubuntu9.3                                                               amd64        Universally Unique ID library - headers and static libraries
ii  x11proto-dev                                                2019.2-1ubuntu1                                                                 all          X11 extension protocols and auxiliary headers
```

---

```
ERROR: Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'.  This happens most      
         frequently when this kernel module was built against the wrong or     
         improperly configured kernel sources, with a version of gcc that      
         differs from the one used to build the target kernel, or if another
         driver, such as nouveau, is present and prevents the NVIDIA kernel
         module from obtaining ownership of the NVIDIA device(s), or no NVIDIA 
         device installed in this system is supported by this NVIDIA Linux
         graphics driver release.                                              

It is not possible to write in /sys/kernel/btf


i2c_hid               processor_thermal_rfim    vmlinux
i2c_hid_acpi          psmouse                   wmi
i2c_i801              r8169                     wmi_bmof
i2c_smbus             raid6_pq                  x86_pkg_temp_thermal
i915                  rapl                      xfrm_algo
idma64                rc_core                   xfrm_user
input_leds            realtek                   xhci_pci
int3400_thermal       rfcomm                    xhci_pci_renesas
int3403_thermal       sch_fq_codel              xor
int340x_thermal_zone  sdhci                     x_tables
intel_cstate          sdhci_pci                 xt_addrtype
intel_hid             serio_raw                 xt_conntrack
intel_lpss            snd                       xt_MASQUERADE
intel_lpss_pci        snd_compress              zstd_compress
intel_pch_thermal     snd_hda_codec
(base) oem@PC83:/sys/kernel/btf$ sudo ls > test
bash: test: Permission denied
```

---

The ubuntu repositories don't work. In every case I meet the following error.

```
(base) oem@PC83:~$ nvidia-smi 
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

ubfan1 said I should use the nvidia-Driver for the new kernel. NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-510.68.02.run has a compiler error:

```
ERROR: Unable to load the kernel module 'nvidia.ko'.  This happens most      
         frequently when this kernel module was built against the wrong or     
         improperly configured kernel sources, with a version of gcc that      
         differs from the one used to build the target kernel, or if another
         driver, such as nouveau, is present and prevents the NVIDIA kernel
         module from obtaining ownership of the NVIDIA device(s), or no NVIDIA 
         device installed in this system is supported by this NVIDIA Linux
         graphics driver release.

   Skipping BTF generation for /tmp/selfgz42390/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-510.68.02/kernel/nvidia-modeset.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
     BTF [M] /tmp/selfgz42390/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-510.68.02/kernel/nvidia-drm.ko
   Skipping BTF generation for /tmp/selfgz42390/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-510.68.02/kernel/nvidia-drm.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
     BTF [M] /tmp/selfgz42390/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-510.68.02/kernel/nvidia.ko
   Skipping BTF generation for /tmp/selfgz42390/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-510.68.02/kernel/nvidia.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
     BTF [M] /tmp/selfgz42390/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-510.68.02/kernel/nvidia-uvm.ko
   Skipping BTF generation for /tmp/selfgz42390/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-510.68.02/kernel/nvidia-uvm.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
```

Comment: Where did you get your Nvidia driver?  The Nvidia drivers from the standard repositories (restricted) will include the "glue" code to recompile the module as necessary when a new kernel is installed.

Comment: I have try to install new nvidia-driver but I get the error vmlinux are unavaiable.

Comment: Is this a compile error? I only see vmlinux in the linux headers for your kernel.  Maybe you need to install the build-essential package.

Comment: Is a compiler error, but the build-essential package was install.

Comment: Edit your original posting for replies, comments may get removed in the future.  Please post the error you got, maybe it's just a missing file because the linux-headers for your kernel is missing.  The package linux-generic should have picked it up, but you can list the headers with dpkg -l |grep headers

Comment: @RainerHoffstadt I have added your 2 answers to this question as *additions* to the original question and also added in the code tags...

Answer (score 0):

Install the proprietary Nvidia driver using the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Reboot to apply the changes.

---

Now, the next time you have a kernel update, the system will automatically update the drivers.

In the future, do not download the proprietary drivers from the Nvidia website. The proprietary drivers are included in the Ubuntu repositories and Ubuntu (Canonical) worked with Nvidia to ensure proper configuration and compatibility with the system.

Answer (score 0):

Hurray,
the new update from ubuntu 20.04 and the newest NVIDIA driver run.(base)

```
oem@PC83:~$ nvidia-smi
Sun Jul 17 18:01:09 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.57       Driver Version: 515.57       CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   50C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      9MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2584      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3302      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```